# Svelte JS and <script> embedded into <main> works (?)

Tags: svelte, program-entry-point

I'm starting to code with Svelte and

I ran into two quirks about script inside main.

Here a code number one:

```
<main>
<p> How are you? </p>

<script>
alert("Welcome everybody!");
</script>

</main>
```

I build this code with Svelte compiler
and the script doesn't work.

Here a code number two:

```
<main>
<p> How are you? </p>

<input type="range" step="1" min="1" max="3" />
<datalist>
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="3"></option>
</datalist>

<script>
alert("Welcome everybody!");
</script>

</main>
```

Code number two shows the alert. Why?

I expected codes run perfectly in both examples.

Answer (score 1):

The alert shows in both cases [in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl). But you are not supposed to do this.

Components should only have at most one `<script>` and one `<style>` and they should be at the top level, not inside some elements. Scripts inside elements will *not* be compiled, so you cannot use any Svelte-specific logic there and the HTML cannot reference the variables via `{...}`.

Comment: Grazie! I used Node v19.6.0 and vite v4.1.2 building and then checked with vite preview Local: http://localhost:4173/ and the result is that Code number one doesn't work while Code number two works. (I thought a script nested in main would not work in the compiler). Is there a difference between REPL and the Svelte compiler in Node? I'll check in REPL but my question is about Node behavior.

Comment: I don't know. If you really care, just compare the compiled outputs directly. But as I said you should not do this anyway.

Comment: REPL and npm run dev of course are not for production, they do not create a dist folder. When you pass in production the difference between code1 and code2 become clear.